# How much should you expect a painter to scrape off exterior of historic house?

Tags: paint

Hundred year old house with wrap around porch and the porch ceiling was painted.
The porch ceiling was scraped, but only in certain areas. I am assuming these were the areas with loose or peeling paint. The problem is some parts of the ceiling look smooth and nicely painted and others look rough and uneven where the paint was not scraped because it wasnt peeling or loose. Some of the wood on the ceiling is much older and more blemished than other areas. I wasnt expecting perfection but the ceiling really only looks good in the areas where the wood is newer and where they scraped. Am I expecting too much of the painting contractor for them to have scraped and prepared the surface better?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When painting a house exterior, do you need to scrape and sand the entire house or just the peeling parts?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/32678/when-painting-a-house-exterior-do-you-need-to-scrape-and-sand-the-entire-house)

Answer (score 5):

At 100 years old, if you want all the paint removed it may become expensive due to the older paint probably contains lead...

It also depends on what you and the contractor agreed - they will usually say something like "remove loose and flaking paint" and paint...

Answer (score 0):

The finish product should look uniform in texture and finish, whether smooth or rough.

When refurbishing “historic” buildings, we try not to make it look new. That is to say, the material, finish, etc. should look appropriate for the age of the building. In this case, it would be normal for the ceiling to be rough and uneven...as long as the surface has been scraped and there is no loose paint.

You indicate that some portions are smooth and some portions are “rough and uneven”. That is not acceptable. The ceiling should appear to have the same texture and finish throughout.

The National Historic Foundation does not like removing old rough wood and installing new smooth wood. Likewise, scraping some paint very well and some areas poorly will create an uneven appearance.

Lead based paint isn’t such a concern on the exterior of the house.

See attached for preparing previously painted surfaces and how to deal with lead based paint:

https://www.thisoldhouse.com/ideas/how-to-strip-years-paint-house